# With which API can I check how many bytes in upload and download I transfer on Mac os x?

Tags: objective-c, macos

is there any api with which I can check how many bytes in upload and download I transfer on Mac os x?

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific, I think.

Comment: I'd like to calculate how many bytes (while my app is running) that my Mac upload and download. Sorry I know that my english is really bad but I hope that you understand now what I wanted.

Comment: I think @Alleria is looking for something similar to what Little Snitch does; he wants to know about uploads and downloads from *any* process running on the system, not just his own.

Comment: Yeah Dave! Thanks for explain better to others my question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to make requests in your app and have an overview of the progress, I suggest you tu check out ASIHTTPRequest. It's an easy to use Objective-C wrapper around CFNetwork that offers a LOT of options and allows you to check the progress by setting a request delegate or using blocks.
Check it out:  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Nope, I want see if is possible monitor how many bytes transferred with my Mac and the Internet while my app is running